# Is "They eat whatever that bugs them" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

In the joke

> **Why are frogs so happy?**
>
> They eat whatever bugs them.

would it be grammatically correct to change the second sentence to "They eat whatever **that** bugs them"? If so, what parts of speech are "whatever" and "that" in this case?

Comment: No, it wouldn't be grammatically correct (or at least, "idiomatically standard") to make that change. *They eat whatever bugs them* is fine as it stands. If you wanted to include ***that***, you could go for *They eat **that which** bugs them*, but that's a somewhat dated/literary usage.

Comment: Or "...whatever **it is** that bugs them."

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage Stack Exchange! Just so you know, the general policy is that when you ask a question about specific words, you're supposed to mention any relevant information from the dictionary entries on these words. Part-of-speech information is found in most dictionaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"They eat whatever that bugs them" is not correct.

Here, *whatever* is a **pronoun**. It is included among the **relative pronouns** by at least some definitions of that term: [relative-pronoun](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/relative-pronoun), [relative-pronoun](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/pronouns/relative-pronoun.html), although it seems to often be left out of lists of more commonly-discussed relative pronouns such as *which* and *who* (unlike these two relative pronouns, *whatever* is not standardly used after other noun phrases).

In any case, no matter what we call it, it is just followed directly by the relative clause; using another relativizing word is unnecessary and ungrammatical.

The word *that* is also traditionally classified as a relative pronoun, although I think I've read some analyses where it is not classified as a pronoun, but just a "[relativizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_relative_clauses#That_as_relativizer_instead_of_relative_pronoun)". From Wikipedia:

> The word *that* [...] is used as a relative pronoun;
>   however, according to some linguists it ought to be analyzed instead
>   as a subordinating conjunction or relativizer. This is consistent with
>   *that* used as a conjunction in (*I said that I was tired*), or implied in
>   (*I said I was tired*).
>
> According to Rodney Huddleston and Geoffrey Pullum *that* is not a
>   relative pronoun but a subordinator, and its analysis requires a
>   relativized symbol R as in (*The film that I needed [R] is not
>   obtainable*). Here R is the covert direct object of the verb "needed"
>   and has "the film" as an antecedent.[15] A similar analysis is
>   required when that is omitted and implied, as in (*The film I needed is*
>   *not obtainable*).
>
> Differences between *that* and other relative pronouns include limiting
>   *that* to restrictive relative clauses and not preceding it with a
>   preposition. Similarities between the relative pronoun *that* and the
>   ordinary conjunction *that* include using (almost invariably) the weak
>   pronunciation /ðət/ and frequently omitting it as implied.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't work. You can say:

> They eat what bugs them.

You cannot add another pronoun 'that' because 'what' is already serving that purpose.

> They eat what that bugs them.  (nonsense)

In this context, 'whatever' is just a more emphatic version of 'what'.  The same rules apply.